# Set log level to DEBUG when running test case in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, junit, netbeans-7, slf4j

I'm working on a Java project in NetBeans IDE 7.0.1. I use slf4j throughout the project, and I'm trying get more information about a JUnit test case that's failing. I run the test case from NetBeans (i.e., I right-click the test and click "Test File").

By default, the log level in the Test Results console window is set to INFO. How do increase log verbosity to DEBUG, so I can get more information about the test case without actually debugging and setting breakpoints?

Comment: This depends on what logger implementation you're using.  Which one are you using?

Comment: In the class under test (we'll call it "MyClass"), I declare the logger like this: private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class); I haven't changed any options, so I guess everything's default?

Comment: No such thing.  You've gotta be using an slf4j impl or else you'll get no logging.  Since you're getting info, you must be using something.  Log4j? JUL? SimpleLogger?

Answer (score 0):

As I said, this depends on your implementation.  Here's a blog post that answers this question though: http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html

Comment: Please don't answer a question just by a link. If the link stops working, your current answer will be useless.